# click event disable other click events

Tags: jquery, html

This is my problem . I have this code:

```
 var state1 = $('.a').clone();
    $('.c').click(function(){
      $('.a').html('<div class="b"></div>');

   }); 
   $('.b').click(function(){
      $('.a').replaceWith(state1);
    });
```

and this is the HTML

```
<div class="a"><img class="c"></div>
```

When i click on the image c, it works but the b click function won't work. I have tried to put the b click function in c click. So it worked but only for the first time. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function needs to be re-associated after each iteration. Try the following code

```
$('.c').click(function () {
    ChangeToB();
});


function ChangeToB() {
    var state1 = $('.a').clone();
    $('.a').html('<div class="b"></div>');

    $('.b').on('click', function () {
        $('.a').replaceWith(state1);
        $('.c').click(function () {
            ChangeToB();
        });
    });
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/mw73enz8/13/)

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching the click event before the element exists. Try using the [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function instead.

```
$('body').on('click', '.c', function(){
    $('.a').html('<div class="b"></div>');
});

$('body').on('click', '.b', function(){
    $('.a').replaceWith(state1);
});
```

This method allows you to attach the click event for elements which will exist in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because you attach event to ".b" before insert to DOM.

Try use delegate events.

```
    var state1 = $('.a').clone();
    $(document).on('click', '.c', (function(){
      $('.a').html('<div class="b"></div>');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.b', (function(){
      $('.a').replaceWith(state1);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

b is a dynamically created element, so the click won't be registered to the new element.
This could solve the problem.

```
    var state1 = $('.a').clone();
    $('.c').click(function(){
      $('.a').html('<div class="b"></div>');

    $('.b').on('click',function(){
      $('.a').replaceWith(state1);
    });
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mw73enz8/11/